# How can one get t-statistic for each coefficient in Math.NET multiple regression

Tags: regression, linear-regression, math.net

I want to perform a multiple regression using Math.NET. For each coefficient I need to get a t-statistic or at least a standard error. How can I do this with Math.NET? I couldn't find it in the docs.

```
x = new double[3][];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) x[i] = new double[10];

y = new double[10];
...
double[] coefs = Fit.MultiDim(x, y, intercept: true);
```

`MultiDim` returns only coefficients without any statistics.